# How to create WinXP style multi-boot for WinXp and Slackware 14.0 on a single harddisk?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, boot, multi-boot, bootloader

I want to create a multi-boot boot loader for Windows Xp and Slacware 14.0 that will look like a Windows Xp boot loader. After Slackware installation I was unable to install lilo an HDD because the configurator was unable to add WinXp boot partition and I don't know why. So to be able to boot into linux I created USB boot stick. It created FAT12 partition on USB drive, but I recreated it to FAT32 partition with proper boot sector by copying all files from pen to some location on hdd, then I used "Memtest86+ USB Installer" which creates FAT32 formatted boot partition and finally copying back files previously copied from pen to hdd back on pen (except ldlinux). I wasn't sure if it will work, but it works !. Kernel loads from pen much faster and I can utilize pen for any other purposes, not only for booting linux (no 16MB space limit as on FAT12). I have WinXP installed on C:\ drive before Slackware installation. I formatted D:\ with FAT32 filesystem (guess why). I placed there (on D:) boot files from USB boot partition and I want to do something with D:\ boot sector and Windows boot.ini to have Windows boot loder with 2 entries being displayed at sturtup (Windows and Slackware) that will boot linux via files on D:\ when I chose Slackware. But I don't know how to do that. My boot.ini looks as fallows:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Windows XP Professional x64 Edition" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect
C:\="Slackware 14.0"
```

I moddified D:\ boot sector after reading this:

http://www.easeus.com/resource/fat32-disk-structure.htm
(section FAT32 Boot Record)

More exactly executable code at 0x5A is the same as on pendrive.

If I replace last line to D:\=... then computer reboots when I chose Slackware. If it starts with C:\= then I receive Boot error. I placed files from pen on C:\ too and same thing happens.

So my questiuon is: Is this possible to do that as I want ?. Did I forgot something ? Did I something wrong ?

Comment: AFAIK `ntldr` does load bootsector from a file. You may try to copy 512B executable code to a file D:\lilo.mbr and add that to your `boot.ini`. But you need to edit lilo's config, as it need's to know where to look for a kernel.

Comment: I've done something similar to that what You wrote. I created a D:\ boot sector backup into D:\bootsect.dos file and added fallowing entry to boot.ini: D:\bootsect.dos="Slackware 14", but this time I received another error: 
Windows could not start because the fallowing file is missing or corrupt:
<Windows root>\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
Please re-install a copy of the file.

btw. I don't know if files created on pendrive by Slackware installer are related to LILO. File names are:

Copying, f1.txt, ldlinux.sys, message.txt, Readme.txt, syslinux.cfg and vmlinuz

Comment: I created D:\windows\system32 folder and copyied ntoskrnl.exe to this folder and got same error.